# Strange mails from my email server

Tags: postfix, smtp

My postfix server and website (WordPress, Apache) resides on the same server box. 2 days ago, we decided to use 3rd party smtp relay host for our mail server. All the DKIM and spf records are in place. They are also validated as domain by the 3rd party smtp provider.

So far, so good. I received message from the 3rd party provider stating that I need to remove gmail, aol etc. free senders from my validation list. Somehow, some people tries to send mails using our smtp server. Seemingly, this originates from the website. Here is the maillog sniplet to show what is going on:

[Maillog excerpt](https://pastebin.com/0SSMN5EN)

> Mar  2 21:55:13 linsvr postfix/pickup[29824]: 25277220008: uid=48
>   from= 
> Mar  2 21:55:13 linsvr postfix/cleanup[31693]:
>   25277220008: message-id=<20190302185513.25277220008@mail.mydomain.com>
>   
> Mar  2 21:55:13 linsvr opendkim[25596]: 25277220008: no signing table
>   match for 'senderemail@gmail.com' 
> Mar  2 21:55:13 linsvr
>   opendkim[25596]: 25277220008: no signature data Mar  2 21:55:13 linsvr
>   postfix/qmgr[9766]: 25277220008: from=, size=638,
>   nrcpt=1 (queue active) 
> Mar  2 21:55:13 linsvr amavis[15091]:
>   (15091-12) ESMTP :10024
>   /var/spool/amavisd/tmp/amavis-20190302T140517-15091-fQptiP_v:
>    ->  SIZE=638 Received: from
>   mail.mydomain.com ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (mail.mydomain.com
>   [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024) with ESMTP for
>   ; Sat,  2 Mar 2019 21:55:13 +0300 (+03) Mar  2
>   21:55:13 linsvr amavis[15091]: (15091-12) Checking: ZnqhsWDKWMOr
>   [127.0.0.1]  ->  
> Mar  2
>   21:55:13 linsvr amavis[15091]: (15091-12) p001 1 Content-Type:
>   text/html, 7bit, size: 157, SHA1 digest:
>   69dbad8db3546a316ce6dbb17f2b13d26c929154 
> Mar  2 21:55:13 linsvr
>   amavis[15091]: (15091-12) wbl: soft-whitelisted (-20) sender
>    => , recip_key="." 
> Mar  2
>   21:55:29 linsvr amavis[15091]: (15091-12) spam-tag,
>    -> , No, score=-6.956
>   tagged_above=-999 required=6.2 tests=[AM.WBL=-20, BAYES_99=3.5,
>   BAYES_999=0.2, DKIM_ADSP_CUSTOM_MED=0.001,
>   FREEMAIL_FORGED_FROMDOMAIN=0.001, FREEMAIL_FROM=0.001,
>   FSL_BULK_SIG=0.839, HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS=0.001,
>   HTML_MESSAGE=0.001, HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG=0.377, KAM_LINKBAIT3=1.5,
>   MALFORMED_FREEMAIL=0.001, MIME_HTML_ONLY=0.723,
>   NML_ADSP_CUSTOM_MED=0.9, NO_RELAYS=-0.001, RAZOR2_CF_RANGE_51_100=2.5,
>   RAZOR2_CHECK=2.5] autolearn=no autolearn_force=no Mar  2 21:55:29
>   linsvr postfix/smtpd[31781]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1] 
> Mar  2
>   21:55:29 linsvr postfix/smtpd[31781]: EAD92220007:
>   client=localhost[127.0.0.1] Mar  2 21:55:29 linsvr
>   postfix/cleanup[31693]: EAD92220007:
>   message-id=<20190302185513.25277220008@mail.mydomain.com> 
> Mar  2
>   21:55:29 linsvr postfix/qmgr[9766]: EAD92220007:
>   from=, size=1708, nrcpt=1 (queue active) 
> Mar  2
>   21:55:29 linsvr postfix/smtpd[31781]: disconnect from
>   localhost[127.0.0.1] 
> Mar  2 21:55:29 linsvr amavis[15091]: (15091-12)
>   ZnqhsWDKWMOr FWD from  -> ,
>   BODY=7BIT 250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok:
>   queued as EAD92220007 
> Mar  2 21:55:29 linsvr amavis[15091]: (15091-12)
>   Passed CLEAN {RelayedInbound}, [127.0.0.1]  ->
>   , Message-ID:
>   <20190302185513.25277220008@mail.mydomain.com>, mail_id: ZnqhsWDKWMOr,
>   Hits: -6.956, size: 671, queued_as: EAD92220007, 16754 ms 
> Mar  2
>   21:55:29 linsvr amavis[15091]: (15091-12) TIMING-SA total 16625 ms -
>   parse: 0.74 (0.0%), extract_message_metadata: 8 (0.0%),
>   get_uri_detail_list: 0.49 (0.0%), tests_pri_-1000: 2.00 (0.0%),
>   tests_pri_-950: 0.76 (0.0%), tests_pri_-900: 1.07 (0.0%),
>   tests_pri_-90: 8 (0.0%), check_bayes: 6 (0.0%), b_tokenize: 2.1
>   (0.0%), b_tok_get_all: 0.95 (0.0%), b_comp_prob: 1.13 (0.0%),
>   b_tok_touch_all: 0.06 (0.0%), b_finish: 0.56 (0.0%), tests_pri_0:
>   11061 (66.5%), check_dkim_signature: 0.49 (0.0%), check_spf: 0.25
>   (0.0%), tests_pri_10: 4290 (25.8%), check_dcc: 4283 (25.8%),
>   tests_pri_20: 1179 (7.1%), check_razor2: 1175 (7.1%), tests_pri_30: 58
>   (0.3%), check_pyzor: 56 (0.3%), tests_pri_500: 7 (0.0%), get_report:
>   0.80 (0.0%) 
> Mar  2 21:55:29 linsvr amavis[15091]: (15091-12) size: 671, TIMING [total 16757 ms] - SMTP greeting: 1.5 (0%)0, SMTP EHLO:
>   0.5 (0%)0, SMTP pre-MAIL: 0.3 (0%)0, SMTP MAIL: 0.8 (0%)0, SMTP pre-DATA-flush: 0.8 (0%)0, SMTP DATA: 41 (0%)0, check_init: 0.4 (0%)0,
>   digest_hdr: 0.3 (0%)0, digest_body: 0.1 (0%)0, collect_info: 0.8
>   (0%)0, mime_decode: 5 (0%)0, get-file-type1: 15 (0%)0, parts_decode:
>   0.1 (0%)0, check_header: 0.3 (0%)0, AV-scan-1: 19 (0%)1, spam-wb-list: 1.1 (0%)1, SA msg read: 0.5 (0%)1, SA parse: 1.3 (0%)1, SA check: 16620 (99%)100, decide_mail_destiny: 8 (0%)100, notif-quar: 0.3
>   (0%)100, fwd-connect: 18 (0%)100, fwd-mail-pip: 8 (0%)100,
>   fwd-rcpt-pip: 0.2 (0%)100, fwd-data-chkpnt: 0.0 (0%)100, write-header:
>   0.3 (0%)100, fwd-data-contents: 0.0 (0%)100, fwd-end-chkpnt: 6 (0%)100, prepare-dsn: 0.6 (0%)100, report: 1.3 (0%)100,
>   main_log_entry: 3.5 (0%)100, update_snmp: 1.1 (0%)100, SMTP
>   pre-response: 0.2 (0%)100, SMTP response: 0.2 (0%)100, unlink-2-files:
>   0.2 (0%)100, rundown: 0.6 (0%)100 
> Mar  2 21:55:29 linsvr postfix/smtp[31699]: 25277220008: to=,
>   relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=17, delays=0.07/0.01/0/17,
>   dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025):
>   250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as EAD92220007) Mar  2 21:55:29 linsvr
>   postfix/qmgr[9766]: 25277220008: removed Mar  2 21:55:30 linsvr
>   postfix/smtp[31784]: EAD92220007: to=,
>   relay=in.mailjet.com[104.199.96.85]:25, delay=0.5,
>   delays=0.01/0.02/0.4/0.07, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK queued as
>   49e13879-c3e9-4012-ba3a-c7caff2b9d41) 
> Mar  2 21:55:30 linsvr
>   postfix/qmgr[9766]: EAD92220007: removed}

Can someone enlighten me on this? And how to fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what exactly they asked of you. You may be an open relay perhaps. But as a random note: most self-hosting e-mail servers from the companies I know of have the top 2 deny all positions occupied by AOL and hotmail. 99.98% of what's coming from there is confirmed spam.

Comment: They ask us to delete any gmail, hotmail, etc address in the sender list. It is not open relay as confirmed by some testing sites. However, I suspect that someone has got the username:password of a legitimate user or WordPress site has a security problem. The code sniplet show that those email originates from the website. But, I don't know how.

Comment: This is strange, why would you authorize such senders initially ?

Answer (score 1):

The Postfix `pickup` process seems to be indicating that these messages are being generated locally by the `apache` user.

Is your WordPress version up to date with security updates? If not, it's probably being hacked. The intruder may have used a WordPress vulnerability that allows them to submit a PHP script of their own to be run by WordPress, and that script is acting as an unauthorized email generator/forwarder. They might even be doing that separately for each email they're sending, and making the script delete itself as it's done its deed.

Otherwise, do you have an unprotected or vulnerable email sending script (PHP, CGI or whatever) in your website?

Your Postfix email server might not be an open relay, and that is what those testing sites are likely to be testing; but something in the Apache + PHP + WordPress combination is allowing the intruder to get in and use the local facilities to send email out. And as far as Postfix is concerned, those messages are originating locally, so they are not subject to relay checks.

As a result, even though your Postfix may not be an open relay, your server taken as a whole effectively is. The intruder just needs to use a bit more complex protocol than plain SMTP to submit messages, but the "exploit an unpatched WordPress" protocol is very well known among spammers.

Comment: This is my guess also.

Comment: WordPress was not updated untill 2-3 days ago. I think you are right. The must be a problem with Apache + PHP + WordPress. I had plugin for newsletter. Deactivated now. I will check it carefully and report if I find anything.

Thank you.